# SSIS package not writing to Excel

Tags: ssis, export-to-excel

Having a bit of an issue with SSIS today.  I've got a package that exports data from 4 tables and puts the data into 4 tabs on a spreadsheet.  Each export has been set up as it's own data flow task.  The package runs without any issues and for each data flow task it says that it is writing rows.  An example is:

```
[SSIS.Pipeline] Information: "Destination - Dev$" wrote 1789 rows.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Information: "Destination 1 - DevC$" wrote 1945 rows.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Information: "Destination 2 - Site$" wrote 1839 rows.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Information: "Destination 3 - DecomDev" wrote 4 rows.
```

Only 1 of tabs has any data in it even though it's saying that it's written rows.  The only warning I'm getting is:

```
[SSIS.Pipeline] Warning: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate
with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, 
run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
```

Which is only showing for 1 of the tasks (the one that is actually exporting data.

Anyone got any ideas?  Not sure if it helps but I'm using SQL Server 2012, Visual Studio 2012 and Excel 2007

Hope you can help.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I got it sorted...  The sheet tabs hadn't been cleared out properly by the last person to run the extract.  So it was inserting the data, but it was starting at the end of sheet (line 7K).

At least it's working!

Thanks anyway.

Alex

Comment: This actually helped me! How could I have overlooked  this. Thanks for sharing